# "Bitlocker" has replaced "Open" at top of Context Menu

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, context-menu

I have been looking all over the place but can't seem to get the right query wording to answer my question.

In the "Right Click Context Menu" of only "Drives" on "This PC" (not folders, files etc.), I have a couple of "BitLocker" options above the "Open" option. This means that double clicking a drive will auto select either "Enable Bitlocker" or "Change Bitlocker Password", depending on whether or not Bitlocker is enabled for that drive.

The standard thing I normally want to do for files, folders and drives is to double click them and open them. How do I get back to this?

I have done so much googling to try and work out how to put "Open" back on the top, but can't for the life of me work it out.

[image]

Comment: @Ramhound Just added one, but can't embed it.

Comment: I am a little confused. Are you concerned about the order of the options?

Comment: As of yesterday, "Open" was the default option, like on basically any file or folder. Double click it, and it opens. Now if I double click the drive, it will go for the top item in the menu which is "Turn on BitLocker", not "Open".

Comment: The only thing I have come across for the manipulation of Bitlocker Context Menu is [at The Windows Club](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/customize-context-menu-of-bitlocker-encrypted-drives-in-windows-10).  You can only add or remove options.  Maybe it will do the trick for you.

Comment: Check the registry key: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\Shell`. Check to mkae sure that the `(Default)` value is: `(value not set)`. If not, right-click the `(Default)` name and select `Delete`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Partial ordering can be done by renaming items of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell` and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers`, but the ones on top are not in registry Plus renaming them isn't a good idea either as then they wouldn't get removed when needed.

Comment: @KeithMiller The default value is indeed "(value not set)".

Comment: @Destroy666 I set up a Bitlocker drive yesterday and after that, the top options (which is automatically selected on a double click) is a Bitlocker option (the option depends on whether said drive has Bitlocker enabled). I didn't and do not intend to change anything in the registry, but am trying to work out how to get "Open" to become the default option again, like it is when double clicking folders and files.

Comment: ...? Not sure how that's related to my comment.

Comment: My question is about working out how to restore the default order, with "Open" at the top. Not reordering the list to my liking.

Comment: @Fieryaleeco All context menu entry positions are controlled via a `RG_SZ` [String] Name: `Position` Value: `Top`, `Middle`, or `Bottom`. The default _Turn on Bitlocker_ entry is in the middle of `Top` - do you know what change to the OS occurred the resulted in it being placed at the top of `Top`?

Answer (score -2):

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following Registry key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\encrypt-bde

3. Here, create a new string value called ProgrammaticAccessOnly. Don't set any value data, just leave it empty.
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
4. Now, go to the following key:

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\encrypt-bde-elev

Similarly as above, create a string value ProgrammaticAccessOnly with empty value

[image]

The result will be as follows:
[image]

Copied from
https://winaero.com/how-to-remove-bitlocker-from-context-menu-in-windows-10/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Edited please remove negative vote now

Comment: Please use correct markdown for monospaced code and list allignments

Comment: I dont know whats wrong in my solution to vote negative